# Why are events not written to files with out_file plugin when append is true?

Tags: fluentd

The reason that I specified `append true` is that I didn't want to create too many small files. And I used `flush_mode immediate` since I wanted events to show up quickly in files.

My fluent.conf:

```
<match hack.**>
  @type file
  path hack
  append true
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
  <buffer>
    flush_mode immediate
  </buffer>
</match>
```

I used `curl` to post events and checked file content.

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8888/hack.access  -d 'json={"no":"1"}'
$ cat hack.20211202.log
{"no":"1"}
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8888/hack.access  -d 'json={"no":"2"}'
$ cat hack.20211202.log
{"no":"1"}
```

I used fluentd 1.14.3 (installed with gem) on macOS.

Ruby versin: `ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-darwin19]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a Fluentd bug. For details, see https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/3569